# How to get length as 0 if the dictionary is not available in Json file while parsing using python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get the length of a dictionary as below . for dictionary "ZZZZ" i may have multiple records available

```
for j in range(len(json_file['entitity'][i]['XXXX']['YYYYY']['ZZZZ']))
```

But if the dictionary doesn't exists in the json file i want to return them as 0

As per the above value i have requirement to get a variable value like below.

```
temp['EMPID'] = json_file['entities'][i]['XXXX']['YYYYY']['ZZZZ'][j]['re']['id']
```

Please help with an suggestion , how can i get "j" variable as 0 if the dictionary doesn't exist. Please find below example

```
"YYYYY": [
        {
          "ZZZZ": {
            "id": "Z1234",
            "type": "p1"
          },
          "id": "wer1234",
          "prop": {
            "dir": "South",
            "Type": "C1"
          }
        },
        {
          "ZZZZ": {
            "id": "Y1234",
            "type": "p2"
          },
          "id": "ert12345",
          "prop": {
            "dir": "North",
            "relationshipType": "C2"
          }
        }
      ]
```

In the above example , i am trying to get the value [ZZZZ][id] ( Value should be : "Z1234" ). In the same way i have one more record with 
value "Y1234". I have totally 2 records because of that i am trying to capture the length as per below command and get the id value.

```
for j in range(len(json_file['YYYYY']))   ------###to capture the lenght as i have 2 records so i am trying to capture length 2
    temp['EMPID'] = json_file['YYYYY'][j]['ZZZZ']['id']   -------##to capture the attribute value
```

But in some cases i may not receive these attributes in my source Json Files, where i want to handle if the attributes are available and have
multiple records then as per above statement i want to get the values else we can populate null values for these id columns.

Comment: If all you are doing is iterating over keys in the 'ZZZZ' dictionary, then you could use the `dict.keys()` method to get a list of keys in the dict.

Comment: @TimKlein. Thanks Tim. Actually in 'ZZZZ' dictionary i have multiple records and thats why i am trying to take that length to a variable. If the dictionary doesnt exist then i want to get as 0 so that my python script will not fail and in the next code of the line while i am trying to read EMPID it should return null.

Comment: Rather than explain that in words, could you edit your post to include a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows exactly what you want?

Comment: @Mike . Hi mike , i have added example . Please have  alook

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using the `dict.get(key, default)` method, supplying an empty list as the default value if the key in the dictionary doesn't exist.

This will allow you to iterate over the keys in the dictionary at the specified key, if it exists, and skip it otherwise.

Ex:

```py
data = {
    'one': {},
    'two': {
        'a': {
            're': {
                'id': 1
            }
        },
        'b': {
            're': {
                'id': 1
            }
        }
    }
}

# Example with empty dictionary
for key in data.get('one', []):
    print(f'data[\'one\'] - {key}: {data["one"][key]}')

# Example with populated dictionary
for key in data.get('two', []):
    print(f'data[\'two\'] - {key}: {data["two"][key]}')

# Example with non-existent dictionary
for key in data.get('foo', []):
    print(f'data[\'foo\'] - {key}: {data["foo"][key]}')
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. But for this case actually i have multi values where i need to captures. I have added above sample example.

Comment: In the above example -- for attribute 'two' we have 'a'  & 'b'. But i have one more 'b'. In some of the files i may get these attributes and in other i may not get get. But when i m trying with the code i am facing "KeyError" --